Cannot get property intellisense result by using Roslyn (dotnet compilation platform)
It appears that I am not able to get a proper intellisense when I try to get the list of elements that should be proposed to the user at the place of the carret.
In the following example, it should return the list of members of the class DateTime, but there is nothing.
What am I missing?
Note: I WANT my code to remain a script.
using System.Collections.Immutable;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Completion;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Host.Mef;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Text;

// using System;var coucou=DateTime.Now;Console.WriteLine(coucou.ToString());
var script = $@"using System;var coucou=DateTime.Now;Console.WriteLine(coucou.ToString());";
var tmp = await GetCompletionDataAsync(script, 64);
Console.WriteLine("Done!");

async Task<CompletionList> GetCompletionDataAsync(string sourceScript, int position)
{
    var compilationOptions = new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary)
        .WithNullableContextOptions(NullableContextOptions.Enable)
        ;

    var scriptProjectInfo = ProjectInfo
        .Create(ProjectId.CreateNewId(), VersionStamp.Create(), "Script", "Script", LanguageNames.CSharp, isSubmission: true)
        .WithCompilationOptions(compilationOptions);
    var host = MefHostServices
        .Create(MefHostServices.DefaultAssemblies);
    using var workspace = new AdhocWorkspace(host);
    var scriptProject = workspace
        .AddProject(scriptProjectInfo);
    var scriptDocumentInfo = DocumentInfo
        .Create(DocumentId.CreateNewId(scriptProject.Id), "Script")
        .WithSourceCodeKind(SourceCodeKind.Script)
        .WithTextLoader(TextLoader.From(TextAndVersion.Create(SourceText.From(sourceScript), VersionStamp.Create())));
    var scriptDocument = workspace
        .AddDocument(scriptDocumentInfo);

    var completionService = CompletionService.GetService(scriptDocument)
        ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("CompletionService could not be retrieved.");
    var completionList = await completionService.GetCompletionsAsync(scriptDocument, position)
        ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("No completion items found.");

    var filteredItems = completionList.Items
        .Where(item => !item.Tags.Contains("Keyword"))
        .ToImmutableArray();

    return CompletionList.Create(completionList.Span, filteredItems);
}


Isn't it meant to be GetCompletionDataAsync(script, 62) instead of 64 ?
